# create update trigger

Tags: sql-server

I have table with 2 columns: id and name. need trigger which at change of records in this table would bring values after updating in other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_tablename] -- replace 'tablename' with your table name
   ON  [dbo].[tablename] FOR UPDATE -- replace 'tablename' with your table name
AS 
BEGIN

        insert into T_tablename_Monitor  -- replace 'tablename' with your table name
        select  NewID(),ID, Name,'After Update',SUSER_SNAME(), getdate() from inserted


END
```

The monitor table might look like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_tablename_Monitor]( -- replace 'tablename' with your table name
    [Row_ID] [varchar](36) NOT NULL,
    [ID] [varchar](30) NOT NULL, -- replace with your type
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL, -- replace with your type
    [Action] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CTime] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2010/09/after-update-trigger-in-sql-server.html) is how to create an update trigger